# findViewById dosen't work in service class in android studio

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, apk

I need to show web page with WebView i can show in MainActivity but i want always work this WebView in service.
want if close the app run service and user online in web site
how can user stay online after closing the app and run javascript in this site

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);

    }
}


public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this is a bad idea to "work with webview in service". Services are for something which happens in backround. Views (any views) are for showing something to the user. There is no intersection with views and services given their natural concerns, so there should not be anything like `findViewById` in a service. You need to search for another solution to whatever XY problem you _actually_ have.

Comment: findViewById can called on a view . And service is a background component its not represent ui. What exactly is your need ?? Edit your question .

Comment: how can user stay online after closing the app and run javascript in this site